# Requirejs with Elasticsearch Angular app throwing "lib/connectors/angular" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, requirejs

I am trying to build Elasticsearch Angular app. I am using require.js.

main.js

```
require.config({

paths : {
'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular',
'elasticsearch' : '../node_modules/elasticsearch/src/elasticsearch.angular',
'app' : 'app',
'coreModule':'coreModule',
'esClient' : 'service/esClient'
},

shim : {

'app':{
'deps' : ['angular','coreModule']
},

'coreModule' : {
'deps' :['angular', 'elasticsearch','esClient']   
},

'esClient' : {
'deps' :['angular', 'elasticsearch']   
}

}

});

require(['app'], function(){

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']); 
});
```

esClient.js

```
define(function(){

var esClient=angular.module('esClient', ['elasticsearch']);

esClient.service('client', function (esFactory) {
return esFactory({
host: 'http://localhost:9200',
apiVersion: '1.5',
log: 'trace'
});
});

});
```

But it is throwing the following errors. Anyone else faced this issue?

Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/connectors/angular" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

makeError @ require.js:166

localRequire @ require.js:1407

requirejs @ require.js:1752

(anonymous function) @ elasticsearch.angular.js:7

coreModule.js:3 coreModule module

app.js:4 App module

angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module 
app due to:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module coreModule due to:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module esClient due to:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module elasticsearch due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'elasticsearch' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Are you sure the `elasticsearch.angular.js` file is being loaded? The path seems to include `node_modules` which, in general, should not be available to the client.

Comment: whats `lib/connectors`

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos It is being loaded. Because the error (Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/connectors/angular") refers to the line No. 7 in elasticsearch.angular.js which points to : 
var AngularConnector = require('./lib/connectors/angular');

Comment: @Vishwanath It refers to the path /node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/angular.js

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I am also following this question up here. Any advice would be welcome. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/211#issuecomment-98943499

Comment: Will need to see your directory structure for better understanding the problem. Also check if you get any errors in Network tab.